# How to search with maven plugin in archiva

Tags: maven, archiva

Using this maven plugin:

http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html

With this command line:

```
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

Maven can connect to Archiva to retrieve the list of dependencies a project is using and check if it uses the latest version of it.

How does it work? Does maven use HTTP to retrieve the information?

Comment: This is really too broad. What are you really interested to know? Yeah the plugin will make some HTTP calls.

Comment: We are currently in the process of creating an application that lists projets according to the number of dependencies they have which are not using the latest version.

Comment: So far, the only solution I've found is to access the pom.xml and metadata.xml files using HTTP request and parse the information. Since Maven already does that, is there any way to reuse it as a project dependency inside my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found everything we need there :
[Eclipse Aether website](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Aether)